# How to automatically upper case first letter in all words in MS Excel sheet with a function or formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a requirement to make first letter as upper case in all the words in my excel sheet. Is there any function to make this change automatically rather than changing all the content manually.

Comment: Please provide sample data and let us know what it is you have tried yourself. Do you mean to use `PROPER()` or do you also need other letters that may already be uppercase remain uppercase?

Comment: Yes, =PROPER() is solution to my task. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Proper()` function.

```
=PROPER(A1)
```

[image]

Or if you want only the first character of cell would be upper case and rest of the words will be lower then use.

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A2,1)) & LOWER(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-1))
```

[image]